# org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MessageHandlerInvocationException

Tags: axon

2019-10-02 15:14:37.833  WARN 60592 --- [onPool-worker-2] o.a.c.gateway.DefaultCommandGateway      : Command 'com.ms.commands.UserPendingCommand' resulted in org.axonframework.messaging.annotation.MessageHandlerInvocationException(Error handling event of type [class com.ms.events.UserPlacedEvent] in aggregate)

I am getting the above error during JacksonSerializer implementation in Axon. It was working fine with the XStreamSerializer.

Below is my JdbcEventStorageEngine code.

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public Serializer serializer() {

            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
            return new JacksonSerializer(objectMapper);
    }

@Bean
    public JdbcEventStorageEngine eventStorageEngine(ConnectionProvider connectionProvider) {
        return new JdbcEventStorageEngine(serializer(), NoOpEventUpcaster.INSTANCE,new JdbcSQLErrorCodesResolver(),connectionProvider, NoTransactionManager.INSTANCE);
    }
```

UserPlacedEvent is stored in event store Database initially with sequence 0 and payload saved as JSON format, But while generating the second event(UserPendingEvent), I am getting above error,

am I missing any configuration?

### UserPlacedEvent.java

```
package com.ms.events;

public class UserPlacedEvent {

    private String id; 
    private String email;
    private String password;

    public UserPlacedEvent() {
        super();
    }

    public UserPlacedEvent(String id, String email, String password) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserPlacedEvent [id=" + id + ", email=" + email + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the exact format of the Event which is failing?
If you're using the `JacksonSerializer`, your message classes are required to contain the right annotation to get it through serialization. Thus I am assuming you've missed those.
Your problem description is however to minimal to deduce whether this is the exact issue.

Comment: Hi @Steven, UserPlacedEvent is stored in Database with sequence 0 and payload as JSON format , But while generating second event, I am getting above error,. this may be not able to convert JSON payload to UserPlacedEvent  java object for processing second event

Comment: I assumed as much, but I am asking whether you can share an actual code snippet of the `UserPlacedEvent` which the `Serializer` fails to deserialize.
With that information I can far better guide you to the solution.
Additionally, I'd like to ask you to update your question with that information rather than making it a comment under here. That would increase clarity for other readers.